# How do I avoid the <img src> attribute being stripped by Gmail?

Tags: gmail, images, html

In the body of an HTML e-mail I send

```
<img style="display:block" alt="Revel Resorts | AC NJ" src="http://revel.mydelphic.com/sites/all/themes/revel/images/r_01.jpg" border="0" height="128" width="20">
```

which renders as an image.

But viewing it in an email I get

```
<img style="display:block" alt="Revel Resorts | AC NJ" border="0" height="128" width="20">
```

The `src` attribute is removed entirely. Anyone know what I may be needing to do to avoid this?

Comment: Your code is most probably sanitised by Google.

Comment: Have you done this? https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=148408

Comment: I'm sending the email, I am looking for things I can do on my end so images show up for others.

Comment: Does this happen even if the receiver uses something else than GMail, like a desktop email client?

Comment: They now download the images to their own server and serve those to the user instead of the original source. (The img src will be something like ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/longstringofletters The image listed in the question is 404, which may be why nothing is showing up (nothing for Google to proxy.)

Answer (score 2):

> Have you ever wondered why Gmail asks you before showing images in
>   emails? We did this to protect you from unknown senders who might try
>   to use images to compromise the security of your computer or mobile
>   device.
>
> But thanks to new improvements in how Gmail handles images, you’ll
>   soon see all images displayed in your messages automatically across
>   desktop, iOS and Android. Instead of serving images directly from
>   their original external host servers, Gmail will now serve all images
>   through Google’s own secure proxy servers.

...

> [image: Previous/New inline images in Gmail]

...

> This new improvement will be rolling out on desktop starting today and
>   to your Gmail mobile apps in early 2014.

**References**
[Images Now Showing - Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.mx/2013/12/images-now-showing.html) Posted: Thursday, December 12, 2013

Comment: This does not help as my images are not proxied as well and src is stripped. Proxied images have an src pointing to a google proxy service.

Comment: Excellent reference answer I found via Google May 2018.  And the question doesn't even match.  +1